# flex: input rules are too complicated (>= 32000 NFA states) (while compiling HLA on 62bit)

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, hla

I'm trying to compile HLA on a 62bit (fedora) and ended up with the following error:

flex: input rules are too complicated (>= 32000 NFA states)

I found directions to address it at below URL:

http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/unnamed_002dfaq_002d88.html

> Increase the definitions in flexdef.h for:
>
> #define JAMSTATE -32766 /* marks a reference to the state that always jams */
>   #define MAXIMUM_MNS 31999
>   #define BAD_SUBSCRIPT -32767
>
> recompile everything, and it should all work.

I downloaded the flex SRPM, made the above changes, compiled and installed it, but it did not work! :(

Comment: Those are the original values. What did you increase them to?

Comment: what changes do you make? show us your code

Comment: I basically doubled them

Comment: You nearly doubled them and you still got '>= 32000 states'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @EJP & @Wayne Sudo
I just found a solution at:

https://www.owlfolio.org/possibly-useful/flex-input-scanner-rules-are-too-complicated/

I modified makefile from

> flex -8 -i ...
>
> to
>
> flex -Ca -8 -i ...

and it worked!

From `flex --help`

```
-Ca, --align      trade off larger tables for better memory alignment
```

Comment: Odder still, `%option align` does not work here when `-Ca` does.